# Use values from the config tables in procedures in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have created a CONFIG table where all hard coded values are stored. So, Now I want to use those values in my stored procedure.

In my config table, I have columns as `FIELDS` and `VALUES`. So first fields is

FIELDS  :                           `ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_COLLECTOR`

VALUE:- `Collector Rings`

So now above data i want to use in my below procedure..

```
FOR REC_LNK IN(SELECT DISTINCT link_id, span_id
FROM R4G_APPDEV.plannedroute_evw
WHERE networktype = T_NETWORKTYPE 
AND link_id is not null 
AND span_id is not null 
AND intracity_link_id is null 
AND networkcategory in ('Collector Rings','NLD Core')   // here i want to use
AND span_id NOT IN (
    SELECT span_id FROM assigned_route_master WHERE link_id IS NOT NULL AND networktype = T_NETWORKTYPE 
)
```

Please suggest how to implement it..!!

**update**

See my table img for more information

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sub-query` in the `IN` clause as follows:

```
AND networkcategory in 
    (SELECT VALUE FROM CONFIG 
      WHERE FIELDS IN ('ONFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_COLLECTOR','ONFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDCORE'))
```

Or you can use the `EXISTS` query as follows:

```
AND EXISTS 
   (SELECT 1 FROM CONFIG C 
     WHERE C.VALUE = networkcategory 
       AND C.FIELDS IN ('ONFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_COLLECTOR','ONFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE_NLDCORE'))
```

Comment: your first answer will give all values included in the list.. suppose If I have more fields and values then ?

Comment: See my update in question for more information

Comment: so which values you want to include in the `IN` list? -- only those which starts with `ONEFIBER_LNK_MIGRATE`? you can use `WHERE` clause in the `IN` sub-query. I have updated the answer considering it

Comment: See, I want to display `Collector Rings`and `NLD Core` dynamically from config table.. So which will be the best way to do this ?

Comment: 1st or 2nd ?? i place of `LIKE` can we use `=` ??

Comment: Both the answer will work now. WIth `IN` clause in the `sub-query` with the exact value of the `FIELDS`

Comment: but is you answer dynamic ? suppose if I made change in config table, it will automatically be seen in procedure..

Comment: Yes. That will be taken care dynamically.